# Android.os.onMainThreadExpection but i have added the INTERNET permission

Tags: php, android

I am using GET METHOD to retrieve data 
but getting this error Android.os.onMainThreadExpection
and i have added the uses permission of INTERNET in the project

Comment: post your code looks like `NetworkOnMainThreadException` means running network operation on ui thread

Comment: for get data from server you have to use AsyncTask to get data.

Comment: In android, any time consuming operation is recommended to be performed in a secondary thread. Read this link. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: @inni: a quick google search for "android network on main thread exception" would give your 1000 results answers to this question. that's why downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a NetworkOnMainThreadException which happens in new versions of Android 3.0 and above if you try to do network operations on the main (UI) Thread. Use an AsyncTask for your network operations.

Answer (score 0):

But You have to do connection in separate Thread. You can use just `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. You can read about that [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Eventually add

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code that access the internet on a thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //your code that access internet here
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I dont really trust asynctask though